# Looking for something more pythonic

Tags: django, refactoring, python

This looks really ugly, it there a way to make it look more pythonic?

```
if self.cleaned_data['string1_val'] == '' and latestSI.string1_val is None :
    if self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] == '' and latestSI.string2_val is None :
        return False
    elif self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] == latestSI.string2_val :
        return False
    else:
        return True
elif self.cleaned_data['string1_val'] == latestSI.string1_val :
    if self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] == '' and latestSI.string2_val is None :
        return False
    elif self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] == latestSI.string2_val :
        return False
    else:
        return True
else:
    return True
```

Comment: More pythonic? Umm what does that even mean?

Comment: @NickLH: used by Python programmers to mean "clean" or "idiomatic", in way that's supposed to sound cool.

Comment: +1 I think this is a great question.  The programmer's alarm bells went off and he sought to take advantage of the language features to code in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your issues stem from `None`s. Clean them up and your logic becomes trivial.

```
cd1 = self.cleaned_data['string1_val']
lsi1 = latestSI.string1_val
cd2 = self.cleaned_data['string2_val']
lsi2 = latestSI.string2_val
if lsi1 is None:
  lsi1 = ''
if lsi2 is None:
  lsi2 = ''
return not (cd1 == lsi1 and cd2 == lsi2)
```

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is that it is specialized to this exact code snippet.  The solutions using variable assignment, the and/or operators, and factoring-out common subexpressions are fully general.  Also, I still find the "cleaned-up" code above to be more difficult to mentally parse than the other solutions.

Comment: I see what you mean. Make the values equal `''` if they are `None` and then you can make cleaner logic. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
def eq(x,y):
    return x == ('' if y is None else y)

if eq(self.cleaned_data['string1_val'],latestSI.string1_val):
    return not eq(self.cleaned_data['string2_val'],latestSI.string2_val)
```

---

Hm. It looks like the question has changed. With the addition of the final `else: True`, the logic can be changed to

```
return not (eq(self.cleaned_data['string1_val'],latestSI.string1_val)
            and eq(self.cleaned_data['string2_val'],latestSI.string2_val))
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this expression is equivalent (I can't test it, since I don't have access to the rest of your code). But, it's really long and hard to understand, I'd rather leave it untouched if I were you:

```
if (self.cleaned_data['string1_val'] == latestSI.string1_val) or (not self.cleaned_data['string1_val'] and not latestSI.string1_val):
    return (not self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] or not latestSI.string2_val) and self.cleaned_data['string2_val'] != latestSI.string2_val
else:
    return True
```

Comment: Leaving the "return True" means there is one more level left.  Care to improve on your answer by using an additional boolean operator and possibly saving intermediate groupings in meaningfully named variables?  Also, consider removing the self.cleaned_data common subexpression.  (Also, an answer isn't good advice if you can't tell whether it is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

The inner if/elif/else chains can be replaced with the and-operator and or-operator.  This substitution should be almost automatic whenever you see `return True` and `return False` for the body of each alternative.

Also, there are multiple references to self.cleaned_data that can be factored-out with:

```
cleaned = self.cleaned_data
```